# How can i make AutoMapper generate this code automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, automapper, automapper-4

I'm new using Automapper i searched a lot for a right answer but it seems i can't get it in my mind correctly so:

i have this block of code

```
    var user = usersDao.FindById(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
    var userDto = Mapper.Map<ApplicationUser, UserDto>(user);
        if (user.Student != null)
        {
         userDto.Account = Mapper.Map<Student, StudentDto>(user.Student);
        }
        if (user.Teacher != null)
        {
        userDto.Account = Mapper.Map<Teacher, TeacherDto>(user.Teacher);
        }
        userDto.Account.User = null;
```

so what i'm trying  to do is i have this property in my `UserDto` class

`AccountDto Account`

both `StudentDto` and `TeacherDto` inherited From it
so i want to make automapper to do self auto mapping to it, if it is from `StudentDto` or `TeacherDto` to `Account`

here is the classes

```
public class StudentDto : AccountDto
    {

    }
public class TeacherDto: AccountDto
    {

    }
public class AccountDto 
    {
        public UserDto User { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

    }
public class UserDto 
{
    public AccountDto Account { get; set; }
}
```

is there a simple solution?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Custom-value-resolvers.html

Comment: I will try it thanks